# what is the use of syntax HashMap<Comparable<?>, something>

Tags: java

I am working on an existing code and encountered following syntax:

```
HashMap<Comparable<?>, something>
```

why we have `Comparable<?>` as key ? In what all cases this will be useful ?

Comment: Because the user of the map does not care about the concrete key type and only of the fact, that the keys are comparable.

Comment: `<?>` is a wildcard. Prevents an expression such as `HashMap<Comparable, Something>` which uses `Comparable` as a raw type. Use of raw types is discouraged since Java 5.

Comment: You have Comparable<?> as key as you want to restrict only those classes which implements Comparable (compareTo method) interface as your key. A class should implement Comparable if it wants to be put in a SortedMap. Please put few more lines of your code to better suggest

Comment: It's a very broad question because you don't mention what you think is strange about this. Please answer this: why would you not use `Comparable<?>` as the key type? (Hint: is your issue with the syntax `<?>`, or do you wonder why it's comparable even though a HashMap doesn't compare, or is the code that is taking things from the HashMap never using the type `Comparable`, etc. etc?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a typing perspective, this means that the keys to the `HashMap` can be any type that implements `Comparable` irrespective of the type parameter.

From an application perspective, it is *not at all clear* what this means.

The normal usage for Comparable is like this.

```
public class SomeType implements Comparable<SomeType> {
    public int compareTo(SomeType other) { ... }
    // etcetera
}
```

In other words, a `SomeType` can be compared with another `SomeType`.  If you tried to compare a `SomeType` with a different type, you would expect a `ClassCastException` ... on the bases that the types are incomparable.  (And IIRC, the javadocs for `Comparable` *recommend* that `compareTo` throws a `CCE` ... for incomparable types.)

So what would the use of a key whose type is `Comparable<?>`?  Would you expect it to be comparable with different types?

- If so, how do you implement a `compareTo` method that can compare `this` with *any* other `Comparable<?>` ... in a meaningful way.
- If not, how is it useful for the key to be a `Comparable<?>`?  You are going to get CCEs ...

In short, I think this is a design error.  I think it would be better to write:

```
  HashMap<T extends Comparable<T>, Something>
```

Comment: In fact with a `Comparable<?>` you can't even call the `compareTo` method. So I don't really get it either unless they are making unchecked casts elsewhere. Or using it as a supertype...like putting `String` and `Integer` in the same Map. Neither of those strike me as useful.

Answer (score 0):

That is a concrete implementation where the only restriction thrown upon the key is to implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. A wildcard is used in order to indicate that any implementation of `Comparable<T>` is supported. The wildcard is neccesary in order to not use a raw type, which is highly discouraged since generics were introduced. In case you use raw types, you'll notice that the compiler will warn you immediately and suggest you to move to generics instead. Notice that `Comparable<T>` interface is generic itself.

This kind of key is useful when you want to apply order upon your keys. Consider a simple scenario where you want to sort the keys. This wouldn't be possible if you'd use a key which is [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) but not comparable.

Answer (score 0):

With `Comparable<?>` as the key, the map definition specifies that it accepts any Object as key that implements `Comparable` interface.

In general, usage of wildcard `Comparable<?>` is recommended over raw type `Comparable`. Reasons described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html).

Technically, for a `HashMap`, it is not useful to enforce keys to implement `Comparable<?>` in any case because `HashMap` will internally not use the `compareTo` method of the `Comparable` interface.

It is going to rely on the `equals` and `hashcode` implementation of the keys.